# how do i get my reply display under a comment

Tags: php

i am try to create a comment for a webpage,but now i succeed in making the comment work,but my problem is how to add a reply and make it display below it's respective comment.have try reading other code examples but i can still figure it out.

index.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>
commenting system
</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php
include("db.php");

$date = date("d-F-Y" );
$nameErr = "";
$n = "at";
$sql = "SELECT * FROM client";
$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
{
 echo $row['fname']."<br>";
 echo  $row['time']."<br>";
 echo $row['comment']."<br>
 <label name = 'reply' value = 'reply' style = 'background:blue;color:white;'><a href = ''>Reply</a></label><hr>
 <style>#form{opacity:0;height:0;}</style>
 <form action = 'cm.php' method = 'POST' id = 'form'>
<input type = 'text' name = 'fname' placeholder = 'Name'></input><br><br>
<input type = 'text' name = 'website' placeholder = 'website'><br><br>
<textarea type = 'text' name = 'scomment' rows = '6' col = '250' placeholder = 'comment here....'>
</textarea><br>
<button type = 'submit'>SUBMIT</button>
</form>";

 }

?>

<form action = "cm.php" method = "POST">
<input type = "text" name = "fname" placeholder = "Name"></input><br><br>
<input type = "text" name = "website" placeholder = "website"><br><br>
<textarea type = "text" name = "scomment" rows = "6" col = "250" placeholder = "comment here....">
</textarea><br>
<button type = "submit">SUBMIT</button>
</form>

 <label name = 'reply' value = 'reply' style = 'background:blue;color:white;border-radius:2px solid black;'>Reply</label>
</body>
</html>
```

cm.php

```
<?php

  session_start();
include 'db.php';

$nameErr = "";
$date = date("d-F-Y" )."  "."  "."  "."  ".date( "H:i");
$fname = $_POST['fname'];
$website = $_POST['website'];
$scomment = $_POST['scomment'];

if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST"){
if(empty($_POST['fname'] && $_POST['scomment'])){
   $nameErr = "Enter your name";
}else{
$sql = "INSERT INTO client (fname, website, comment,time) VALUES ('$fname', '$website', '$scomment','$date')";
$result = $con->query($sql);
}
}
header("Location:index.php");

?>
```

Comment: please i need  help no one is answering my question.